# VS402864: No artifact type found corresponding to id PipelineArtifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using a Azure DevOps/VSTS release pipeline to deploy artifacts created during a build, but I am unable to explore the artifacts in the pipeline editor.

> VS402864: No artifact type found corresponding to id PipelineArtifact.
>   Make sure that the artifact type extension is available and try again.

[image]

I am able to explore the artifact contents just fine on the build summary.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the new (in preview) Pipeline Artifacts feature. Based on the dates of the discussion at the bottom of the [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=vsts), I think there are still some defects to be worked through to get it out of preview.

I'd recommend you use Copy Files and Publish **Build** Artifacts until it comes out of preview.

Comment: Or perhaps just the 'Publish Build Artifacts' task.

Comment: Yup. That works too. I tend to use copy files first because I build I'll build up a directory tree from multiple sources before I publish them. Makes my release pipelines easier.